# string indices must be integers in a defaultdict, CSV File

Tags: python, string, csv, integer, defaultdict

I have .csv file, about ramen and brands, varieties and ratings. I want to figure out, which Brand uses the Variety "Tom Yum" the most. I tried it with a defaultdict but i get the *error code: string indices must be integers*

This is my code so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tomyum = []

for row in liste:
    if "Tom Yum" in row["Variety"]:
        tomyum.append(row["Brand"])
        


d = defaultdict(int)

for row in tomyum:
    for brand in row['Brand']:
        d[brand] += 1
d
```

Anyone any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tomyum` is a list of strings. Hence, in the following loop: `for row in tomyum`, `row` represents a string. That's why you cannot do `row['Brand']` in the next line, since you can access only indices in `row`, i.e. `row[0]`, `row[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know how i can get the result i want?

Comment: I'm not sure what the result that you want is...

Comment: I want a dictionary which contains how often a Brand uses the Variety "Tom Yum": e.g "Brand1" : 5, "Brand 2": 4....

Comment: So I believe you can just do `for brand in row:` instead of `for brand in row['Brand']:`, since as mentioned - `row` is an element in `tomyum ` which is a list of brands...